# Deleted and frozen rooms shown as possible migration targets

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

A user posted a screenshot of his profile page to show off and accidentally included his OpenID accounts, so I tried to move the post to a deleted room.

For science.

The operation seems at first possible:

[image]

...however, attempting to choose that room (or the frozen room) is a no-op.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For science, hmm...?

[image: science lolcat]

Well, well, well.

Fixed now.